# AlertDialog.builder setSelection

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm using AlertDialog basically as a spinner for a user to select.  I would like to setPosition of the of setItems array based on what they may have chosen before.  For example if they had selected "Age 40" before, I would expect I could have "40" be at top of the list when they reopen the AlertDialog.  Any ideas?

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new Builder(this);
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btnAge:
        b.setTitle("Age");
        String[] ageArray = { "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24",
                "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34",
                "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44",
                "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53",
                "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63",
                "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73",
                "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83",
                "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93",
                "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99" };
        b.setItems(ageArray,
                new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            //
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            // 
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                });

        b.show();

        break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to save the age in a global variable (such as: int previousAge;) when an age is selected.  Then the next time the alert dialog is displayed you can set the age that was previously selected with:

```
b.setSingleChoiceItems(ageArray, previousAge, new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       ...             
    });
```